# EFCore with NewtonSoft Json serialization from scaffolded database : ignore not loaded navigation properties

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am creating an ASP.NET Core application and I have scaffolded my database to an EFCore DbContext.

All navigation properties one-to-many are defined as `public virtual ICollection<Type> NavProp { get; set; }`, and the scaffolder add some initialization in the entity constructor as `NavProp = new HashSet<Type>()`.

I have a data controller that returns data from the DbContext : `return this.DbContext.MyData.First();`

How can I avoid the Json serializer to serialize the navigation properties that I have not explicitely included in my query ? This will avoid loading unneeded data, and also reference looping.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to transfer them then you would not need to include them in your query...

Query only the columns you need and store them in DTOs (Data Transfer Objects) like:

```
return this.DbContext.MyData.First().Select(x => new MyDataDto { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name });
```

and a DTO class like:

```
public class MyDto {
    // All the properties you want to tranfer
    public int Id { get; set }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // your props...
}
```

With this approach you have control over what is transferred.

Comment: Hi, is there any alternative other than using DTOs ?

Comment: Yes there is. Use annotations, [DataContract] to the class and [DataMember] on properties you want serialized.